# how do i view methods/step through code during orientation change in android

Tags: android, configuration

I have a simple `WebView` application which takes some time to load up when i change the orientation. In order to optimise i would like to get an understanding of the processes involved when changing orientation. I added dummy activity lifecycle methods with text being sent to logcat using the Log.d method. i however can not see any of these methods being used when i change the orientation.

I did a bit of digging and apparently i can also override the behaviour of the orientation configuration by using onConfigurationChanged, I coded the `onConfigurationChanged` method with some logcat statements but the program does not appear to go through this method as well.

Can you tell me how do i view  the methods involved in configuration change so that i can optimise my code. as per this "[article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)"  configuration change should result in `onDestroy` being called, followed by `onCreate`. I cant see the `onDestroy` method executed, instead the program stops at `onStop` and does not appear to proceed further.

i checked in the logcat and each time i changed the orientation the `WindowManager` followed by the `ActivityManager` is fired.

can you guys tell me how to view the transitions? is there any setting i need to set someplace?

Comment: Where do you put your `Log` lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the `android:configChanges` to your manifest file?

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) the documentation says `onConfigurationChanged` will be called only if you have  `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the manifest file. Otherwise Android itself will handle all config changes.

Answer (score 1):

Android Baby, 
Try adding OnPause and OnResume overridden methods and add your breakpoints to those methods. They will be definitely called on Orientation changes.

Comment: thanks for the replies guys,

i discovered that i had not overriddenshouldoverrideurlloading method and hence it was firing a browser. And hence my program was stopping in onStop method.

Answer (score 0):

If, as described in the article you refer to, you have put the following line in your manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

then your activity won't execute onPause/Stop/Destroy as it finishes in one orientation and then restarts in the other, running through onCreate/Start/Resume.

This is because you have told the application that you will handle the orientation changes yourself when you insert that line. If you write an override for onConfigurationChanged(..), then it will run through that.

Comment: thanks for all the replies.

i discovered what the issue was. i had not added a webviewclient to override the shouldOverrideUrlLoadingand this was resulting in a browser application being started, and as result my program was in onStop method.